# <form:option value="0"> validation is not working using jquery validation

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using chosen.js and jquery validation pluging but below code is not working,I am not get any error.please help me how to validate this using jquery validation pluging.

```
<form:form method="post" id="clienteditform" action="updateClient.htm" name="clienteditform" cssClass="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="eReg" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <form:select cssClass="chosen-select" cssStyle="width:450px;" id="country" name="country" path="cusDTO.client.cl_country_id">
                <form:option value="0">Select country</form:option>
                <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="country_id" itemLabel="country_name"/>
                </form:select>

            </div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

             $(".chosen-select").chosen();

             $.validator.addMethod("validateCountry", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || value != '0' ;
            }, " Please select country");

             $("#clienteditform").validate({
                 rules: {

                     "cusDTO.client.cl_country_id":{
                         validateCountry : true
                     }
                 }

             });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $(".chosen-select").chosen();

         $.validator.addMethod("validateCountry", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || value != '0' ;
        }, " Please select country");

         $("#clienteditform").validate({
             rules: {

                 "cusDTO.client.cl_country_id":{
                     validateCountry : true
                 }
             }

         });
         $('#country').rules('add', {validateCountry:true});


    });
```

hope it solve your problem